# Transition to full Window (not screen)

Tags: html, css

I have a report page, where I have my menus, my headers, footers, etc. However I would like to have an option that the report content can be enlarged to full window size (not full screen) with a transition. I'm experimenting with this example:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_zoom_hover

My main problem is I can't make it transition the movement too, not just the enlargement. It instantly jumps to the top left corner without any transition, while the 100% width and 100% height transition works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.zoom {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transition: all 1s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Zoom on Hover</h1>
<p>Hover over the div element.</p>
  
<div class="zoom"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've been searching for a solution, however most of the results are regarding full screen, and not full window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are changing the position to `fixed` and your `top`/`left` values are immediately considering thus the jump. Also I don't think there is a CSS solution to have a transition from the static position to the fixed position by specifying `top`/`left` only on hover. The rule of transtion is to have an initial value and a final value.

An idea here is to rely on some JS in order to set a the intial value of `top`/`left` values and allow the transition to work fine:

```js
function getPosition(element) {
  var xPosition = 0,
    yPosition = 0;

  while (element) {
    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft + element.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (element.offsetTop + element.clientTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: (xPosition - document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft),
    y: (yPosition - document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop)
  };
}
var e=document.querySelector('.zoom');
var pos = getPosition(e);
e.style.left=pos.x+ 'px';
e.style.top=pos.y + 'px';
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.zoom {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transition: all 1s;
  top: 0!important;
  left: 0!important;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Zoom on Hover</h1>
<p>Hover over the div element.</p>

<div class="zoom"></div>
```

To be more accurate you need to adjust the values on the window scroll and window resize:

```js
function getPosition(element) {
  var xPosition = 0,
    yPosition = 0;

  while (element) {
    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft + element.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (element.offsetTop + element.clientTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: (xPosition - document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft),
    y: (yPosition - document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop)
  };
}
var e = document.querySelector('.zoom');
var pos = getPosition(e);
e.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
e.style.top = pos.y + 'px';

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var pos = getPosition(e);
  e.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
  e.style.top = pos.y + 'px';
});
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var pos = getPosition(e);
  e.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
  e.style.top = pos.y + 'px';
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.zoom {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transition: all 1s;
  top: 0!important;
  left: 0!important;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Zoom on Hover</h1>
<p>Hover over the div element.</p>

<div class="zoom"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: I have one more smaller question, is it possible to have the transition work in reverse too? I added the 
  transition: all 1s; to the zoom class, but it's instantly jumping back to 0 height, and only after 1 sec instantly goes back to original height.

Comment: @CAJ69I you will need more JS for this a the reverse order make the position static again and suddenly the top/left are no more considered ... you are intrested in more complex code with JS?

Comment: In that case I'll figure it out, it will be some good practicing possibility. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

By default the `position` property of `.zoom` is `static`, transition is not able to handle change of display type.

So you may need to set `position: absolute;` for `.zoom` and preset the position.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.zoom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 120px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transition: all 1s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Zoom on Hover</h1>
<p>Hover over the div element.</p>
  
<div class="zoom"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: This looks nice, however when I add more elements before the content (a new header, a description, etc.), this "always fixed" method makes it float in front of the content. For example if you duplicate the <h1> and <p> lines, they will be behind the green box.

Comment: you mean what by display is relative?

Comment: it's not relative but static

Comment: Is there any way to go to full window size even with the relative position property? In your example if I add a few more lines between the <h1> and the green box, the green box will simply be in front of them.